# Server asking for password even after adding ssh keys

Tags: server, ssh

This was working fine but not sure suddenly stopped working.

I have added my id_rsa.pub key of localhost to authorized_keys of .ssh folder on server. When I try to login to server (running ubuntu 12.10) from localhsot with

```
ssh account@ip
```

it asks for password. I am not sure what I am doing wrong since it looks to be pretty straight forward process and it was working fine earlier. Any help ?

Comment: check by adding public key in known_hosts file.

Comment: @Tingrammer: The `known_hosts` file is for the purpose of the connector in making sure the server they're connecting to is correct. This shouldn't influence what authentication method is used by the server.

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh-copy-id`?

Comment: Have you had a look into the `/var/log/auth.log` ? Do you see error/warning related to SSH ?

Answer (score 2):

There could be any number of problems from incorrect permissions to an encrypted home directory.

In general, `ssh-copy-id` is the best method to transfer the keys as it automates the process.

```
ssh-copy-id -i key_name user@server
```

See http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_keys#Transfer for details

If you are using an encrypted home directory, however, you need to configure your ssh server to look for the keys in an alternate location. In that event, you edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and edit the location of the key file.

If all that fails, post the output of

```
ssh -vvv user@server
```

the -vvv option will show verbose error messages.

Comment: Encrypted home directory was the issue for me. Didn't see anyone else pointing this out before. Look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my environment I had two accounts (**acct1** and **acct2**) 
I set up my ssh keys in **acct1** and it worked properly.

Then I copied the .ssh directory from **acct1** to **acct2** and tried it there, but it didn't work as expected, asked me for the password...

The reason was:
The ownership of the files in .ssh directory. The acct2 user was not the owner of those files.

```
-rw-------  1 root   root    408 Aug 10 16:53 id_rsa.pub

-rw-------  1 **root**   **root**   1675 Aug 10 16:53 id_rsa

-rw-r--r--  1 acct2 acct2  444 Aug 10 16:54 known_hosts
```

So I just changed the ownership of files to acct2 user.

**sudo chown acct2:acct2**

Now it look like below and it works properly.

```
-rw-------  1 acct2   acct2    408 Aug 10 16:53 id_rsa.pub

-rw-------  1 **acct2**   **acct2**   1675 Aug 10 16:53 id_rsa

-rw-r--r--  1 acct2 acct2  444 Aug 10 16:54 known_hosts
```